# Form.Dirty is false when it should be true

Tags: ms-access, vba

I notice that in one of my form(bounded to a query), when I do this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Dirty(Cancel As Integer)
    MsgBox Me.Form.Dirty
End Sub
```

It should pop up the value 'true', because this is onDirty event, right? But actually i get a 'false'. Why?

Comment: The Form property is unnecessary: `Me.Dirty` is exactly the same thing as `Me.Form.Dirty`. This is because .Form is the default property of a form's class module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That’s because the dirty event is where you can cancel the change and roll it back. It is after the dirty event that the form actually gets marked as dirty. The chain of events for a text box for example is this

KeyDown > KeyPress > BeforeInsert > Dirty > KeyUp

Hope this helps